# g++ linker throwing undefined reference to xxxx

Tags: c++, c, g++

I am trying to compile and link my project using g++. The source files in my project are written in c++, but the library I am trying to link against is written in c, and it doesn't have extern before the functions in the header files to define them as written in c language.

Here's my command for compiling and linking:

**g++ socketd.cpp main.cpp -I src/common -L src/common -lwrappers -lerror -lpthread**

I am getting the following errors:

**socketd.cpp:(.text+0xc6): undefined reference to `error_sys(char const*, ...)'**

And error_sys is already defined in liberror library.

So my question is, why am I getting this error? Is it because I have to re-write the functions and define extern before them for the libraries written in c language?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Looks perhaps like a missing extern "C" {}.

Comment: @bmargulies it is, the question states that on the second sentence ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A library written in C is unlikely to have the `extern "C"` guard around its functions, but this is not a problem for C++ code. Simply provide it yourself around the include:

```
extern "C" {
    #include <my_c_header.h>
}
```